# Creating Portable class library for Xamarin.mac

Tags: xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

We are developing a mac application using Xamarin.mac. Since we want the same application to be developed for windows as well, we decided to write all the business logic inside a Portable class library. Is PCL Supported for Xamarin.mac?.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier approach for sharing code between a Windows and a Mac app (talking from first hand painful expirience) is something called "Shared Project". What it will do is it will "Inject" itself into the build process for a specific platform, and as long as the references you use are accessible on both platforms, all will be well.